# Set a different classpath for just one grails command

Tags: grails, groovy, maven, jar, classpath

I need to set a different `classpath` for one single grails `xxx` command.

The point is that my application uses latest version of `commons-httpclient`. I have no problems with this. But after building my application I need to use `grails maven-deploy` to store my `war` file in a `webdav` repository, and the command conflicts with the latest version of `commons-httpclient`. This command works great if I add `commons-httpclient-2.0.2.jar` in the `classpath` (lib folder for example), but the app will fail on trying to use the regular features that depends on `commons-httpclient`.

I need to add this other jar in the `classpath` just for running the `maven-deploy` command, any ideas?

I'm using jenkins (huson) to build the app, so, any tips on making the solution achievable with grails jenkins plugins will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Does the `grails maven-deploy` command conflicts due to another dependency on `httpclient`?

Which one is it? May be you could exclude the dependency it?

Comment: Hi Peter, actually the problem is that when using maven-deploy with **--repository=webdav** the implementation uses wagon-webdav provider, that depends on **commons-httpclient-2.0.2.jar**. My application uses another plugin grails-aws, that depends on **commons-httpclient-3.1.jar**, so the conflicts occurs.

Comment: The only moment my application would require **commons-httpclient-2.0.2.jar** would be when using **maven-deploy** command. That's why I need to change just on this moment. Any tips?